# Dictionary of attributes and values

Tags: python, hash-map

In the code below, I have a dictionary of attributes and values. I am checking to see if the value if an attribute is True, and if so adding the attribute to a list for later processing (it becomes part of a SQL group by).

This code works fine, but I was wondering how it could be more "Pythonic". Note that the `col_map` dict is actually a lot bigger.

```
   col_map = {      
        'dim_3a_group_checkbox': 'pn_group',
        'dim_3a_family_checkbox': 'pn_family',
        'dim_3a_root_checkbox': 'pn_root',
    }
    # get an object with the attributes (eg:dim_3a_root_checkbox) as True / False
    supply_kpi = self.browse(cr, uid, ids, context=None)[0]
    group_by = []
    for key, value in col_map.iteritems():
        x = getattr(supply_kpi,key)
        if x:   # only add if attribute is True
            group_by.append(value)
    print group_by
```

Example results

```
    ['pn_family', 'order_type', 'pn_group', 'categ']
```

Comment: This question is incomplete. To help reviewers give you better answers, please add sufficient context to your question. The more you tell us about [what your code does](//codereview.meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/1226) and what the purpose of doing that is, the easier it will be for reviewers to help you.  The current title states your concerns about the code; it needs an [edit] to simply *state the task*; see [How to get the best value out of Code Review: Asking Questions](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2436) for guidance on writing good question titles.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would do

```
supply_kpi = self.browse(cr, uid, ids, context=None)[0]
group_by = [col_map[key] for key in col_map if getattr(supply_kpi, key)]
```

- Iterating with list comprehension is much more efficient.
- You don't build iteritems list of tuples.

Comment: Cf @sundar's answer to avoid calling `cal_map[key]` for each key.

Comment: @Josay is using iteritems() preferred over cal_map[key] ?

Comment: It is indeed. That's exactly what `iteritems()` is for. The iterator provides you the keys and values instead of the just the keys so that you don't have to retrieve the values yourself. More about this on Raymond Hettinger's talk at pycon US 2013 : video : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OSGv2VnC0go / slides : https://speakerdeck.com/pyconslides/transforming-code-into-beautiful-idiomatic-python-by-raymond-hettinger-1

Comment: using `iteritems` is fine. There is a little cost of going through the generator and building the tuples. I would say around 15% from what I see ... The look-up in the dictionary has a big cost but depends also how often `getattr(supply_kpi, key)` is true. Doing `col_map[key]` can actually be faster.

Answer (score 6):

total groupby can be written in single line list comprehension

```
groupby=  [value  for key, value in col_map.iteritems() if getattr(supply_kpi,key) ]
```